# configuration VS2010 for GreedyProjectionTriangulation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, struct, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a code based on PCL 1.6, using functions as OrganizedFastMesh and Poisson, and it works well. But When I add [this code](http://justpaste.it/ddur) to use GreedyProjectionTriangulation function VS2010 return this error:

*Error  51  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __cdecl pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation::performReconstruction(class std::vector > &)" (?performReconstruction@?$GreedyProjectionTriangulation@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@EEAAXAEAV?$vector@UVertices@pcl@@V?$allocator@UVertices@pcl@@@std@@@std@@@Z)  C:...\pcl_surface.obj*

Does it need an additional file.lib to include?

Which ones? Or what else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago,the same error occurred in my code (with two similar errors).
I added the lib file **/lib/pcl_features_debug.lib** to the **linker-->input**, and it works.

**VS2010(X64) debug mode**

Comment: if you find some similar errors in your code,like "error 2001,or error 2019 ,unsolved external symbol,pcl::****::*** ",maybe you just need to find some related lib file to add.